# How to not show error messages when resetting form?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been doing some research on this and still can't find a good solution. Basically I have this basic form, that if I click on **Clear button** I want to rest form. Currently it resets it , but you will see that it shows the error message of the field for a **half of a second** then disappears. My question is: How to reset the form so it clears all the values from each field and **never** show any error message. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-ywc1xb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
clearForm(){
  this.registrationFormGroup.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your logic to check for specific error like this:
`userlastname.touched && userlastname.hasError['minLength']`.
As for using valid/invalid - I think there is a time where you have blurred out the field and show error message when you click on button.

**EDIT**
The above answer was wrong. The only way I was able to get it working is do a *double* *reset*. You need to call `clearForm` on both `mousedown` and `click`.
If you only call `clearForm` on `mousedown` it will set the form to touched on `click`(mouseup), on the other hand, if you only call `clearForm` on `click`, the erorr message would have been appeared when `mousedown`. [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clear-form-without-flicker?file=app/app.component.html) fork from yours.

Comment: can you please provide a stackbliz or live demo? Thanks

Comment: @progx I have edited the answer - the first attempt was wrong.

Comment: try again please

Comment: I can see your stackbliz now, but the issue is still present. Let's say I type a single character on field 1 then click on clear button I still see the error message for a half of a second

Comment: I tested it with the `lastname` and it was working - didn't realise that first one has `required` in it. 
Made some changes to make it work - it's a hack, the solution is not the most graceful, it just work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to modify your form like this :

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationFormGroup" #registrationFormDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
```

and the `clearForm` function like this :

```
clearForm(registrationFormGroup: FormGroup, registrationFormDirective: FormGroupDirective){
  registrationFormDirective.resetForm();
  registrationFormGroup.reset();
}
```

Because the form status is in the FormGroupDirective and not in the FormGroup.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Can you provide a stackblitz or live demo?